# Flutter webview authentication and javascript injection

Tags: javascript, flutter, authentication, webview, code-injection

```
onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
  webViewController.evaluateJavascript(
  '<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">alert("Hello World")</script>');
},
```

The above code not working in flutter webview javascript injection can anyone help me how to inject javascript code in flutter webview

Answer (score 0):

Enable javascript

```
 WebView(
          initialUrl: 'https://....',
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
)
```